# Routing leads based upon their time added?

Tags: formula, leads, datetime

I'm trying to create a lead assignment rule that routes a lead based upon the time it was created. It appears that the only functions available are only based upon date, not time.

I looked in the data loader and the format of the created date field entries look like:

```
2015-10-05T12:45:50.000Z
```

How can I get the time out of that and then create a formula that evaluates to true at a certain time range every day? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email Templates: Conditional Greeting Based on Time of Day](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93701/email-templates-conditional-greeting-based-on-time-of-day)

Answer (score 2):

Use a formula field, or multiple formula fields.

I'd make one formula field that extracts the current hour of the day:

[Finding the Hour, Minute, or Second from a Date/Time](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US#getting-hms-from-datetime)

**Created_Hours__c:** `VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate - 6 ), 12, 2 ) )`

And another field that does your business logic:

**Route_Lead__c:** `AND(Created_Hours__c >= 6, Created_Hours__c <= 18)` -- Lead Created after 6am and before 6pm.

You can then drive your routing off of whether Route_Lead__c is True or False.